# Reading file error in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am brand new to Python and am having a terrible time trying to read in a .csv file to work with.  The code I am using is the following:

```
>>> dat = open('blue.csv','r')
>>> print dat()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable
```

Could anyone help me diagnose this error or lend any suggestions on how to read the file in? Sorry if there is an answer to this question already, but I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)? There are a bunch of examples. Or perhaps the [Python MOTW on the CSV module](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/)? Many more examples.

Comment: So when I use `print dat` I get the following `>>> print dat
<open file 'trims.csv', mode 'r' at 0x6fffff496f0>` but I was expecting to see my data from the .csv

Comment: `print dat.readlines()` or `.read()`.

Comment: So try following one of the examples provided in the links I shared.

Comment: This is the first thing to learn; as soon as you get `open()/read()` straight, look for some examples of how to use the `csv` module (since that's what you need to process your data). Better yet: Work through a good python tutorial, instead of trying things at random.

Comment: Since you are new to Python, the problem you are having is that you are trying to invoke a file object like a method by calling `dat()`, which is not an operation. It's like saying `2()` for an integer. Similarly, simply printing `dat` will print the file object representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `read` the file:

```
dat = open('blue.csv', 'r').read()
```

Or you can open the file as a csv and read it row by row:

```
import csv
infile = open('blue.csv', 'r')
csvfile = csv.reader(infile)
for row in csvfile:
    print row
    column1 = row[0]
    print column1
```

Check out the [`csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for more options for working with csv files.

Comment: Do I have to specify the path to the file? Or does python search everywhere for it?

Comment: @ZERO If you just specify the path like this: `infile = open('blue.csv', 'r')`, the `blue.csv` file needs to be in the same directory as your script.  In other words, you are setting a path *relative* to your script.  You could also set an *absolute* path to the file like so `infile = open('/Users/ZERO/pythonproject/blue.csv', 'r')`.

Comment: My csv file has headers.  How would I read it in without those?

Comment: `csvfile` is a list of rows in my example.  In Python, the first item is represented by index 0.  So we want to skip item 0 and start at item 1 (the second item).  To skip the first item, you can slice the list like so: `csvfile = csvfile[1:]`.  If you only want the first 30 rows, `csvfile = csvfile[1:30]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `read` in order to read a file

```
dat = open('blue.csv','r')
print dat.read()
```

Alternatively, you can use `with` for self-closing

```
with open('blue.csv','r') as o:
    data = o.read()
```

Comment: So I shouldn't be using the `'w'` flag?

Comment: @ZERO The `w` flag is for writing to a file. `r` is for reading